# Has AccessEnum been replaced by anything?

Tags: ntfs

Has [AccessEnum](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897332) been replaced by another tool?   I mean it does what I want it to do, but it doesn't work across UNC paths it seems a little old.

Comment: As far as I can tell, no, it hasn't been deprecated or replaced. I'd imagine the reason it doesn't work over UNC is that it'd create a huge amount of traffic.

Comment: I think Powershell is the replacement.